# DataGridViewComboBox column in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, merge, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I am fail to clear the DataTable Bind to the (cnsmNm) datagridviewCombobox column. On New Button Click I am clearing the Data

```
 dtCnsmbl = dsCnsmspplr.Tables[0]; 
            dtCnsmbl.Rows.Clear();
            cnsmNm.DataSource = dtCnsmbl;
            cnsmNm.DisplayMember = "cnsm_Name";
            cnsmNm.ValueMember = "cnsm_Id";
```

On TextBox Validating (Outside DataGridView) I am Bind data to Datagridview ComboBox column

```
                dtqttndtls = dssplrdtls.Tables[3];
                DataTable dtmerge = new DataTable();
                dtmerge.Columns.Add("cnsm_Id", typeof(Int32));
                dtmerge.Columns.Add("cnsm_Name");
                foreach (DataRow drmrg in dtqttndtls.Rows)
                {
                    DataRow drnew = dtmerge.NewRow();
                    drnew["cnsm_Id"] = drmrg["cnsm_Id"];
                    drnew["cnsm_Name"] = drmrg["cnsm_Name"];
                    dtmerge.Rows.Add(drnew);
                }
                dtCnsmbl.Merge(dtmerge);
                cnsmNm.DataSource = dtCnsmbl;
                cnsmNm.DisplayMember = "cnsm_Name";
                cnsmNm.ValueMember = "cnsm_Id";
```

After filling the Datagridviewcombobox column I am not able to clear the DataTable. I am new to Datagridview.

Comment: try catch (Exception) only...,

Comment: put break points and see does it hit exception block.

Comment: no, i check it, i think there is something else...,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i think instead of this

```
        dtCnsmbl = dsCnsmspplr.Tables[0]; 
        dtCnsmbl.Rows.Clear();
        cnsmNm.DataSource = dtCnsmbl;
        cnsmNm.DisplayMember = "cnsm_Name";
        cnsmNm.ValueMember = "cnsm_Id";
```

write this

```
       DataTable newdata = dsCnsmspplr.Tables[0].Clone();
       cnsmNm.DataSource = newdata;
        cnsmNm.DisplayMember = "cnsm_Name";
        cnsmNm.ValueMember = "cnsm_Id";
```

Comment: there is no DataBind property...,cnsmNm is the column name of DatagridviewComboboxColumn

Comment: First time it is working for the second time it is not working

Comment: what do you mean by second time? please explain your process like when u add and when u clear

Comment: 1.On Form_Load i am Clearing the Data bind to the Datagridview comboBox Column. 2.After saving data to database again i click the New button in that process it is not working

Comment: have you called the same thing after u click the new button

Comment: Yes , i am calling the same function

Comment: cnsmNm.DataSource = null; try this one